# C# Linq predicate generation remove all null values from list

Tags: c#, linq, predicatebuilder

I am trying to generate filter code using linq predicates.  When I use a predicate with a object != null:

```
public static Expression<Func<ContactPermitsSearch, bool>> PermitNumberNotNull()
    {
        Expression<Func<ContactPermitsSearch, bool>> predicate = contactPermit => contactPermit.PermitNumber != null;
        return predicate;
    }
```

which is called by:

```
public static IQueryable<ContactPermitsSearch> FilterByNameMailingPermit(this IQueryable<ContactPermitsSearch> queryable, string search, bool filterOn)
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<ContactPermitsSearch>();

        predicate = predicate.And(PermitNumberNotNull());

        var filtered = queryable.AsExpandable().Where(predicate);
        return filtered;
    }
```

The SQL statement that is generated does not include the PermitNumberNotNull predicate statement.

Thoughts on fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the code. I'm sure that if you inspect `predicate` in the debugger after merging it with `PermitNumberNotNull()` you'll see that the not null predicate is part of the expression tree.

The only reasonable assumption is that EF knows that `contactPermit.PermitNumber` can't ever be null because it's **required** property. Therefore, it simply ignores the predicate.

Comment: This is the answer!  Thank you!  It's a varchar(7) not nullable.